# Maven fails with classpath errors and recover when a new project is opened

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have the following pom.xml file:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <start-class>com.example.Main</start-class>
</properties>

<groupId>SpringProject</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringProject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.phoneBook.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

As you can understand, it's a spring-boot application. When I run it, I get the error:

> Elasticsearch “StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging
>   implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath.”

and log4j2 doesn't act properly.

However, the solution that I found is to open a new project, copy all files, and then surprisingly everything works perfectly and this error doesn't show.

Yesterday, I had another problem that I also got an error for something with classpath and again opening a new Project and copying files solved it.

Do you know what can cause such errors and whether there is a more comfortable way to resolve it without opening a new project and copy files?

Comment: You built your project with a "clean", like "clean install"?

Comment: The first important thing I see is that you are mixing up different Spring Boot versions..which you should simply not do...